# File corrupted after upload to S3 using Lambda and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying upload the file using Lambda to S3 way API GateWay, i am using the code below, the file is sent to S3 such as show the images 'test_using_postman.png' and 's3_file.png', however when I try open, the show message the file corrupted such as show the 'open_file_with_problem.png'. The images are below.

Somone know the happened ?

Thank you!

***Images:***

Test Using Postman: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eenEnvuMQU28iI_Ltqzpw9OlCvIcY5Fg

S3 File: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b1_CmIhzfc8mQj_rwCK6Xy30gzoP6HcK

Open File with problem: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o54rLB9wWF1KxdUOkq3xAGVET7UWoqgf

***Code NodeJS:***

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

module.exports.arquivo_upload =  (event, context, callback) => {

  let BUCKET_NAME = 'XXXXX';

  let fileContent = event.body;
  let filePath = 'upload/';
  let fileName = crypto.createHash('md5').update('niby_'+Date.now()).digest("hex");

  s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});

  var uploadParams = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, 
      Key: filePath+fileName+'.png', 
      Body: fileContent,
      ContentType: "image/png"
    };

  s3.upload(uploadParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {

      console.error(err);

      callback(null,{
        statusCode:400,
        body: JSON.stringify(err),
      });

    } if (data) {

      //TODO: Call other api to save file name

      console.info(data.Location);

      callback(null,{
        statusCode:200,
        body: JSON.stringify(data.Location),
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is the file base64 encoded? API gateway can encode the files by default.

Comment: What about API Gateawy?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem! I sending file using base64 to API Gateway and lambda functions setup parameter "ContentEncoding: 'base64'".

```
  var uploadParams = {
  Bucket: config.s3.bucket_name, 
  Key: config.s3.file_path+fileName+obj.extension, 
  Body: buf,
  ContentEncoding: 'base64',
  ContentType: obj.content_type,
  ACL: "public-read"
};
```

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit? I ran into the same problem